# Writing a number if another field is not null in QGIS Table

Tags: qgis, table

I am trying to make a condition in a new column that if there is a value in another column, a number will be filled accordingly

For example

Here's the table

[image]

If there is a value in "watt_3" I want to have 3

If there's only in "watt_1" I want to get the value of 1

Iv'e thought of these logical rule because I not really good at coding, it's not correct

```
CASE

WHEN "watt_3"  NOT is_empty_or_null THEN 3

ELSE

WHEN "watt_2"  NOT is_empty_or_null THEN 2

ELSE 1

END
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your requirement correctly, try:

```
Case
when "watt_1" is not NULL and "watt_3" is NULL and "watt_2" is NULL then 1
when "watt_3" is NULL then 3
when "watt_2" is NULL then 2
end
```

It fills your field in this order:

1. with 1 if watt_1 is not empty but both other fields are.
2. with 3 if watt_3 is empty
3. with 2 if watt_2 is empty

Answer (score 1):

So, I've figured it out, I guess I'm just bad at coding

```
Case when "watt_3" is not NULL then 3 when "watt_2" is not NULL then 2
when "watt_1" is not NULL then 1 else 1 end
```

Thanks